# Validate Form with PHP AND JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, validation, forms

Is it possible to validate a form with **PHP** and **JavaScript**? I'm currently able to do both using my existing `form`, but only on an individual basis.

My overall goal is this:

1. Validate form using **JavaScript** client side and present any errors to the user immediately.
2. If **JavaScript** validation passes, a flag is created and then the **PHP** script can begin.

When doing my **JavaScript** validation, I use the following code within the `form` tag:

```
<form id="Enroll_Form"  action="review.php" method="post" name="Enroll_Form" onsubmit="return Enroll_Form_Validator(this)" language="javascript">
```

If I want to process the **PHP** validation I'm forced to rename the action to the `PHP_SELF` file (or simply the same file name I'm using) and remove the 'onsubmit' function.

Comment: Why do you think that form action must be PHP_SELF (of the same file name) ?

Comment: the action must be of the same page if I want to results returned by the PHP validation to appear on the same page (as well as using the posted data to populate once submitted if an error is found).

Comment: My preferred way is to use the same PHP functions to validate both server-side and client-side through AJAX. Simply include the validation functions in the page that the AJAX will request, and do those functions again as the form is processed server-side.

Comment: @Byron, using that method, you lose a key benefit of client-side validation: instant feedback.

Comment: @nickf, Maybe it's just me but the majority of the validation I've had to do involve database queries anyway so it seemed a pretty natural way to do it. It also prevents the need for other people working on the project to learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED** in responce to comments

First of all, javascript can't be a secure validator, for obvious reasons! it can be a fancy way of displaying alerts and notice but is just sugar!

Real validation must be done in PHP or other server-side language as well as on Database side by checking and formatting values!

This simple script is just a demostration of how you can built a smart validator, but of course is just a proof of concept!

---

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/aceze/29

```
$(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        var error = false; // flag

        $('.email,.digits,.empty,.some').each(function() {

            var check = this.className;

            if (check == 'empty') if (!checkEmpty(this.value)) error = true;

            if (check == 'digits') if (!checkDigits(this.value)) error = true;

            if (check == 'email') if (!checkEmail(this.value)) error = true;

            if (check == 'some') if (!checkSome(this.value)) error = true;

            if (error) {
                $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
            } else {
                $(this).css('border', '1px solid green');
            }
        });

        if (error) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

---

Then regarding the `<form>` action, you don't need to have the path of the php page in it, but you must use AJAX for make the POST **OR** just leave the `review.php` where is see theese  snippets below:

```
  // FIRST SNIPPET action="#"
           if ( error == false ) {
           //if all is ok give our form it's php
           $(this).attr('action','review.php');
           } else {
           // error  
           // place false here so the form don't submit if validation fail!
           return false;
         }

  // SECOND SNIPPET action="review.php"

          if ( error == true ) {
        // form submit only if validation pass
           return false;
           } 

  // THIRD SNIPPET action="#" AJAX

    if ( error == false ) {
           // success
           } else {
           // error  

         }
     // this false prevent the form submit in anycase, cause we use AJAX
     return false;
```

Comment: I think the example you showed is interesting but not sure it gets where I'm trying to go. Is there any actual JS validation going on here or is this all server-side? I'm not going to lie - the field validations I have to complete for this site are numerous and not fun.

Comment: @J M 4 This form just checks to see if the form fields aren't empty. There isn't any data checks here. Use PHP regular expressions or whatever for that

Answer (score 0):

I don´t really see what the problem is, if your `onsubmit` action returns `false` in case of a non (javascript) validated form, the form simply doesn´t get submitted **if** javascript is enabled.

As soon as the form gets submitted, the php can do whatever it wants, validate, return errors, etc.

Comment: what I am saying here is that the javascript is in fact running but the PHP will not if I use it in this manner. onsubmit functions override 'action' within form fields

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, but off the top of my head; you don't need the `language="JavaScript"` in your form for it to use the `onsumbit` event handler. If that event evaluates to `true`, then the form will be submitted as normal (so PHP will see it and can do its validation).

It's good to see you're not relying on client-side validation. It's trivial to disable JavaScript in a browser. One should *always* validate one's input.

Comment: fredden, you are right - i have removed the deprecated language. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely too much on JS for this kind of stuff. Yes, you can validate to prevent users errors, but someone could easily create a `.html` and do

```
<form action="http://yoursite.com/review.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And bypass any JS validation you have. Validate in PHP as you would if you hadn't any JS validation.

Comment: use both! JS allows you to make it "pretty" with the form field being highlighted. harder to do in PHP IMO